# Record ipod gameplay

Tags: iphone, ipod

I want to record Plants VS Zombies and upload the gameplay video on YouTube. Is there any program can do this?

Much appreciated for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For an unjailbroken iPhone, it is not possible to do it directly on the device.

However, if you jailbreak, you can get [Display Recorder](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/displayrecorder/) from the Cydia Store. It costs $4.99. There are other alternatives, but Display Recorder is so far the best I hae tried.

Answer (score 0):

On cydia there is display recorder, but you need to jailbreak your iphone. on virgin phones there is no way to do it... If you are running your own app you can run it in sumulator and use some mac screen capture tool...